# Trying to sort by column is causing an error

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a simple script that I am trying to make to sort a specific column, but for some reason the code I've taken directly from the examples online (from the API) is causing an error message:

```
Cell reference out of range (line 7, file "Code")
```

My code is as follows:

```
function Remove_Duplicates() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = 2;
  var col = 7;
  cellStr = ss.getRange(row,col).getValue();
  Logger.log(cellStr);
  ss.getRange("G2:H100").sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}]);


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the example for [sort(sortSpecObj)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj), Column A has column number 1, Column B has column number 2, and so on.

The error occurs because the range to be sorted is G2:H100 but column A (column 1) isn't included.